# How to dynamically create vertices in glVertexPointer() in openGLES

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

I have a set of textures which I need to draw at different vertices such that every texture is visible.I cannot define a static set of vertices since I load the textures dynamically and I dont know how many textures will be loaded everytime ( i choose them based on a condition).

This is how my code looks as of now.

```
for(int i=0;i<num_img;i++)
{    
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    glRotatef(rot, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[i]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Is there anyway to dynamically generate vertices that can be passed as final argument of glVertexPointer() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the maximum number of vertices that you will use? Maybe you could create the `vertices` array to be that maximum size then in the first parameter of `glVertexPointer` you only pass the number of vertices that you actually use.

Comment: Isn't the first parameter to glVertexPointer() the number of coordinates per vertex, not the number of vertices in the pointer? From the docs "Specifies the number of coordinates per vertex. Must be 2, 3, or 4. The initial value is 4."